# How to improve toggle menu with CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have implemented a functional menu of  **chapters(left)** and **Units(right)** that works as i want and seen on the image i have attached. The problem is that it is slow, as i generate the CSS and JavaScript dynamically, so as to define the right ids for each element.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't read all the code but you seem to be doing a lot of database queries, which takes time, more than the time that it takes to generate Javascript and CSS dynamically. Try reducing the number of SQL queries.

Comment: Ok i understand what you say. But i do so many queries because each chapter and unit has a unique id which i can only retrieve from db.

Comment: I saw that, but you can get all the data you need from menuChapters and menuUnits in two queries and store the data in a PHP variable. Then you do everything you want on this variable. It is clearly better than doing a SQL query on each loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should get your data from the Database all at once:

What about doing this:

```
SELECT menuChapters.id, menuUnits.id
FROM menuChapters INNER JOIN menuUnits
ON (menuChapters.id = menuUnits.chapter_id)
WHERE menuChapters.class=$get_class AND menuChapters.course=$get_course AND menuChapters.visibility=1
ORDER BY menuChapters.chapterOrder ASC, menuUnits.unitsOrder ASC
```

This should give you a list where you have the id of your chapter and the id of your unit for each row.

I didn't try the code, so it might have some issues.

Comment: @alex Happy that it helped. Do not hesitate, to store data into variables when it can be useful multiple times:  for instance, except if I am wrong, `$sql_dyn_1` and `$sql_dyn_3a` are exactly the same.